# Upper bound on a difference of two square root functions

Tags: real-analysis, upper-lower-bounds

> I am trying to find an upper bound on $\sqrt{x+y}-\sqrt{x}$, $x\geq 0,y\geq -x$.

I would think $\sqrt{x+y}-\sqrt{x}\leq \sqrt{|y|}$ but I'm not sure how to prove that because although both sides are positive, squaring them does not prove the desired inequality. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true both sides are positive (take $x> 0$ and $y =-x$). Anyway,
$\sqrt{x+y}-\sqrt{x}\leq \sqrt{|y|}$ is equivalent to
$$\sqrt{x+y}\leq \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{|y|} \tag {1}.$$
Here both sides are $\ge 0$, thus $(1)$ is equivalent to
$$x + y \le x + 2\sqrt{x}\sqrt{|y|} + |y| .$$
This is obviously true.